# How to render 2 slide shows component separately in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to implement a team selector component for my mobile application that is being implemented using react-native and the component will be like the following;

[image]

The slide show is an open-source template (https://github.com/kamalpandey/react-native-image-slider-show)

Now my problem is that when I change the country from slide show, the team slide show needs to be rendered automatically while the county slide show animation continues.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Select your team!</Text>
        <SlideShow 
        dataSource={[
            { 
              url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any'
            },
            { 
              url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' 
            },
            { 
              url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' 
            }
        ]}
        onPositionChanged = {(index)=> console.log("position index", index)}/>
        <SlideShow 
        dataSource={[
            { 
              url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any'
            },
            { 
              url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' 
            },
            { 
              url:'http://placeimg.com/640/480/any' 
            }
        ]}
        onPositionChanged = {(index)=> console.log("position index", index)}/>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here? Do you want to keep both sliders in sync?

Comment: Also keep in mind that you're using a badly supported package, always try to find one with the biggest community to help you with such challenges! [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20native%20slider&ranking=popularity)

Comment: You mean I am using badly supported source-code for the slide show component?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the cause of the problem. It was more meant as advice.