# Is that possible to render any component from the other at any time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, render

I have a question about react-native component possibilities and to explain my question, I have implemented the following sample code;

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <FirstChild/>
        <SecondChild/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class FirstChild extends Component {
  render() {
    return( 
    <View>
      <Text>{Math.random()}</Text>
      <Button 
        title='Render second child'
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

class SecondChild extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>{Math.random()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are 2 child components and I want to trigger only the render function of the second component or render the second component from the first component at any time.

Is that possible in react-native and how can I do that ?

Comment: why do you want to trigger it? it is impossible. the render  method is handled by react-native system to render visual dom

Comment: If it is possible, I am gonna use the solution to fix this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858370/how-to-render-2-slide-shows-component-separately-in-react-native?noredirect=1#comment103989371_58858370

Comment: for this situation, you can compose it in a component. so you can control the second component. like the `react-native-dropdown`

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, what you need is to hide the 1st component as a result of the button click on the 1st component. If that's the case, you can do it as follows.

- First, add a state variable in the parent component that indicates whether to render the 1st component or not.
- Then add a function to the parent component to update this field and pass it as a `prop` to the 1st component.
- Conditionally render the 1st component based on the value of the above state variable.

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showFirst: true
    };
  }

  hideFirst = () => {
    this.setState({
        showFirst: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        {
            (this.state.showFirst) &&
            (<FirstChild hideFirst={this.hideFirst}/>)
        }
        <SecondChild/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

- In the 1st component, call the `hideFirst` prop method when the `onClick` event is triggered on the button.

```
class FirstChild extends Component {
  render() {
    return( 
    <View>
      <Text>{Math.random()}</Text>
      <Button 
        title='Render second child'
        onClick={() => this.props.hideFirst()}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The second component is not rendered when I test your solution and in my case, the parent component can render these 2 children in startup case than when any press comes to button just second component need to be rendered. (The first component shouldn't be rendered one more time through the button press)

Comment: I updated my answer according to your above details